# Can I connect to API using Informatica Cloud service?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, iics-di

Can I connect to API using Informatica Cloud service? If yes, can you please guide me through process? I am new to Informatica Cloud service, so please provide example along with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use APIs in Informatica Cloud Data Integration. Please refer the [documentation](https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-data-integration-connectors/current-version/rest-v2-connector/introduction-to-rest-v2-connector/rest-v2-connector-overview.html) for REST v2 connector.

Comment: Thank you for documentation. If possible can you please provide any documentation on step by step process of using REST V2 connector ? Thanks in advance!